# Azure Storage: Cost related query

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage, azure-cost-calculation

I have been trying to understand the data transfer cost within the storage account from one container to another

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Here it says 10 Write operation will cost $1.00 but what does x10,000 operations mean below the box?

Does it mean if I copy 10 blobs from one container to another it will cost me $1 but what actually means x10,000 operations?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are charged per chunks of 10,000 operations. In this case, you are going to pay $1 for 100,000 operations as you gave a 10x multiplicator.

You have the detailed pricing available at this [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/blobs/).

Comment: Meaning if i break a 1 GB file in to chunks of 10000? thats's what 10,000 operation mean? does Azure internally brakes a file in to chunks while using copyBlob api?

Comment: Yes that's correct, 1GB chunked into 10,000 pieces will lead to 10,000 operations. Each SDK has its own internal chunking mechanism, you can have a look at how azcopy copy works for instance with the --block-size-mb setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#options